# Icefaces components: Error [status: malformedXML code: 200]: XML Parsing Error

Tags: spring, tomcat, icefaces

I have a strange problem that happened when I install my application in CentOS. I use tomcat 7, jdk 1.7, spring 3.0.5, springsecurity3.1, Facelets and icefaces 2.1.

I developed my application on windows7 and everything works well, but when I try install my application on Centos 5 my components don't work.
So, for instance, when I try to use ice:panelCollapsible I don't get any error on server log but on Firebug I get this error:

```
[window] Error [status: malformedXML code: 200]: XML Parsing Error: junk after document element
Location: http://192.168.0.60:8080/myapp/faces/jsp/mypage.xhtml
Line Number 149, Column 8:
</html><?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
-------^
```

this is mypage.xhtml code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
<title>IGNORED</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/layout.xhtml">
<ui:define name="windowTitle">
#{msgs.myApp}
</ui:define>
<ui:define name="sidebarLeft">
<h:link outcome="/jsp/work/work">
<ice:outputText id="newWork" value="#{msgs['menu.newWork']}" />
</h:link>
<br />
</ui:define>
<ui:define name="content">
<div class="container">
<ice:form>
<ice:panelCollapsible id="tasksPanel" expanded="true">
<f:facet name="header">
<ice:panelGroup>
<ice:outputText id="tasksHeader"
value="#{msgs['myApp.tasks']}" />
</ice:panelGroup>
</f:facet>


<ice:dataTable id="tasksTable"
binding="#{myAppBean.tasksTable}"
value="#{myAppBean.tasks}" var="task" width="100%">
<ice:column>
<f:facet name="header">
<ice:outputText value="#{msgs['myApp.tasks.taskName']}" />
</f:facet>
<ice:outputText id="taskName" value="#{task.taskName}">
</ice:outputText>
</ice:column>
<ice:column>
<f:facet name="header">
<ice:outputText value="#{msgs['myApp.tasks.actions']}" />
</f:facet>
<ice:outputLink value="myApp/task.xhtml?id=#{task.idtask}">
<ice:outputText value="#{msgs['action.details']}"
styleClass="link" />
</ice:outputLink>
<ice:commandLink actionListener="#{myAppBean.removeTask}"
value="#{msgs['action.delete']}" rendered="#{task.done}"/>
<ice:commandLink actionListener="#{myAppBean.closeTask}"
value="#{msgs['action.done']}" rendered="#{!task.done}" partialSubmit="true" />
</ice:column>
<f:facet name="footer">
<ice:outputText visible="#{myAppBean.showNoTasks}"
value="#{msgs['myApp.tasks.noTasks']}" />
</f:facet>
</ice:dataTable>
<br />


</ice:panelCollapsible>
<br />

</ice:form>
</div>
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Thank for helping.

Greetings

Comment: I got a simmilar Problem with IceFaces Push and Primefaces sometimes i get a [window] Error [status: malformedXML code: 200]: During update: layout_s not found error in FireBug ... noting on Server side. Do you got any Solution ?

Comment: I'm another user with the same message appearing in FireBug, `[window] Error [status: malformedXML code: 200]`. Mine occurs when toggling a popup.

Comment: This subject is outdated but I have a similar issue.